# Splitting Array Based on Value of Individual Elements

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I'm attempting to split an array into four separate arrays based on the value of individual elements. It's significant to note that the range that defines arrays are bounded by equal intervals.

For instance, consider the following array:

`C = [(1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 9), (4, 19), (5, 7), (6, 12), (7, 1), (8, 6)]`

I desire the final result to appear as:

`C1 = [(1, 0), (2, 5)]

C2 = [(3,9), (4, 19)]

C3 = [(5, 7), (6, 12)]

C4 = [(7, 1), (8, 6)]`

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so we can help. Here is how you should ask a question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
C = [(1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 9), (4, 19), (5, 7), (6, 12), (7, 1), (8, 6)]
length = len(C)//4

C1 = [C[i] for i in range(length)]
C2 = [C[i] for i in range(length, length*2)]
C3 = [C[i] for i in range(length*2, length*3)]
C4 = [C[i] for i in range(length*3, length*4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this code:

input:

```
l = [(1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 9), (4, 19), (5, 7), (6, 12), (7, 1), (8, 6)]

l1 = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if i%2 ==0]
l2 = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if i%2 !=0]
print(*zip(l1,l2), sep='\n')
```

will generate:

```
((1, 0), (2, 5))
((3, 9), (4, 19))
((5, 7), (6, 12))
((7, 1), (8, 6))
```

This can handle any length of your original list: l1 and l2 are odd and even numbered element respectively, then zip it. Currently they are tuples, but you can iterate thru it with a for loop and get whatever format you want eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip:

```
C = [(1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 9), (4, 19), (5, 7), (6, 12), (7, 1), (8, 6)]

C1,C2,C3,C4 = map(list,zip(C[::2],C[1::2]))
```

output:

```
C1 = [(1, 0), (2, 5)]
C2 = [(3, 9), (4, 19)]
C3 = [(5, 7), (6, 12)]
C4 = [(7, 1), (8, 6)]
```